# Django template: Display object in template not using view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

This almost feels too simple but I'm trying to show an object in my template and I can't use a function/class-based view because this needs to be on the base.html template (for all views).

I totally get the problem as I can make it work when I define the object as a variable in a view. My question is really about how to make it work when not using the view.py

base.html

```
<!-- works -->
{{ user.username }}
<!-- doesn't work -->
{{ custom_model.field }}
```

I checked out [The Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/) and using their story model as an example.

---

**Additional Info**
To hopefully address Willem Van Onsem's question.

I'll be adding sitewide headlines in the navbar. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

models.py

```
class Headline(models.Model):
    description = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

context_processors.py # Additions after question created

```
def active_headline(request):
    from portfolios.models import Headline
    return {'headline': Headline.objects.filter(active=True)}
```

settings.py # Additions after question created

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                # for site-wide headlines
                'portfolios.context_processors.active_headline'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

base.html

```
{{ headline | truncatechars_html:150 | safe }}
```

- getting some rendering issues here where the HTML doesn't show but the queryset text and brackets [] show on my page.

Comment: You can make a *context processor*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors but it is not very clear to me how you are going to retrieve a *single* object. Based on what parameters?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added a bit more to the question to hopefully give it more context. So if a headline is active it will then show at the top of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "inject" extra data to your templates by making use of [custom *context processors* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors):

You can thus define a context processor, for example in `app/context_processors.py`:

```
# app/context_processors.py

def some_model_object(request):
    from app.models import SomeModel
    return {'my_object': SomeModel.objects.first()}
```

Then in your settings, you add your custom context processor:

```
# settings.py

# …

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # …
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # …
                'app.context_processors.some_model_object'
            ]
        }
        # …
    }
]
```

If you now render a template, then Django will automatically add the items returned in the dictionary of the custom context processor to the context of the template.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback! I did not know about this and will test it out. I added a bit more context to my question which at first I didn't think was necessary but the possible solution seems more elaborate than I first imagined. I need to get offline right now but expect a response soon to this solution!

Comment: With the help of your solution everything is working but some last unwanted renderings, I think I'll figure out soon enough. Everything listed under "Additional Info" in the question. I Will post a solution for rendering issue when I get it. However, I may use a django package for this problem instead as it would be a better solution as my project scales. Something like https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications or https://github.com/pinax/pinax-notifications